# Unable to reset HTML video on iPhone to start from the beginning

Tags: javascript, iphone, html5-video, quicktime

Using a shared video object I'm loading and playing different source movies dynamically.  Resetting the current time like this works fine on the desktop;

```
$('video').bind('loadeddata', function () {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.currentTime = 0;
});
```

...but while QT is playing on the iPhone the newly loaded movie continues from the previous position of the play head.  I tried using "loadedmetadata" also without success.  Is there another way to restart the QT player?

Comment: Changing the src on the video element alone is enough to reset the currentTime to 0 on desktop. iOS does this funky thing where you can't change the currentTime until it has media data for the location you're changing it to.

You could try the 'canplay' event instead of 'loadedmetadata', but that is a pretty crap solution :/

Comment: I added more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266437/html5-video-currenttime-not-setting-properly-on-iphone) along with my solution.